# Evaluate the limit of the sequence: $\lim_{n_\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate the limit of the sequence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}$$

---

My try:

Stolz-cesaro: The limit of the sequence is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$$

For our sequence:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n!}-\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})\cdot(1+\sqrt{n+1})-(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}\cdot(\sqrt{n-1})}{\left((1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})\right)\cdot(\sqrt{n}+1)}$

Which got me nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:
$$
(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})
$$

Take the root from each pair of parentheses and multiply them, then:
$$
(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n}) > \sqrt{n!} \iff \\
\iff \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}
$$
Going back to original we have that:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})} \le \frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\sqrt{n!}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}
$$

But the function is greater than $0$ and hence using squeeze theorem we conclude that:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n} = 0
$$

Hence the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

$(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n}) \ge \sqrt{1}\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdots \sqrt{n}= \sqrt{n!}$, hence

$0 \le \frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})\cdot(1+\sqrt{2})\cdot (1+\sqrt{3})\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 3):

We have that

$$\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\prod_{k=1}^n\big(1+\sqrt{k}\big)}=\frac1{\sqrt n}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+\sqrt{k}}\le \frac1{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Elements on the denominator are multiplyting

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}{\prod_{k=1}^n\big(1+\sqrt{k}\big)}=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{1+\sqrt{k}}<\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}\to 0
$$